# What do you call the walking lanes in lecture rooms?

Tags: word-request

[image: Lecture theatre seating]

What do you call the walking lanes in lecture rooms? You can't call it a stair, because it's not really a stair, you can't call it a corridor either. The only word I can think of is walking lane, but I doubt it's called that. Isn't there a more specific word I can use?

Comment: What would you call it? and what does your (bilingual) dictionary call that?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This (and any similar "lane") is usually called an *aisle* (pronounced "eye-ll"):

> [**aisle**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/aisle) (n): 1. A passage between rows of seats in a building such as a church or theatre, an aircraft, or train. 1.1 A passage between cabinets and shelves of goods in a supermarket or other building.

Example:

> Carelessly tapping away on her cell phone as she entered the lecture hall, the student stumbled off of the top stair of the center **aisle**, and might have fallen headfirst all the way to the bottom if her friend hadn't caught her by the arm.

---

Side note:  The [etymology of "aisle"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/aisle) is a definitive illustration of why English spelling is so bizarre.  "Aisle" originally derives from the old French *ele* (wing) from the Latin *ala* (presumably from the way it separates the people in a large room like the *wings* of an army).  So far, so good.

At some point in the 15th century, "aisle" became confused with the Middle English "ile" (island), and, some time after, both gained a silent "s" (possibly to re-associate "isle/island" to the Latin *insula*).  Shortly after, "aisle" gained an "a" to match it with the updated French spelling *aile*.

Perfectly logical, right?

Comment: Plural: `aisles`. There is often more than one aisle in a large room, including along the sides.

Comment: A former work colleague once observed that the only reason spelling bees are interesting is because English is, as he put it, such a bad language. A German spelling bee in comparison would be incredibly dull and might go on for weeks!

Comment: @GregBacon  German spelling bees would go on so long because it takes forever to spell each word.  Half the audience would have fallen asleep before the first contestant got finished spelling *Donaudampfschiffahrtselektrizitätenhauptbetriebswerkbauunterbeamtengesellschaft*  :D

Comment: @Andrew - which google helpfully translated to "Danube steamship electricity main factory construction substation" German is *amazing* in creating words like this spell!

Comment: 'He took his bride-to-be up the aisle'. Better than clambering over seats?